# Cannot parse date with LocalDateTime

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, format

I'm trying to parse a date string using Java8 [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) without any success.

The exception is: **DateTimeParseException: Text '28-APR-2015 01:25:00 PM' could not be parsed at index 3**

The string to parse is: **28-APR-2015 01:25:00 PM** and the pattern I'm currently using is **dd-LLL-yyyy hh:mm:ss a**

Where am I wrong?

Thank you

Adding example code:

```
String text = "28-APR-2015 01:25:00 PM";
DateTimeFormatter fromatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-LLL-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
try {
        String out = LocalDateTime.parse(text, formatter)
        System.out.println(out);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Solved using the response from @Florin using:

```
    DateTimeFormatter tertiaryFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive().parseLenient().appendPattern("dd-LLL-yyyy hh:mm:ss a").toFormatter();
```

Comment: Can you include a short but complete example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I've managed to reproduce this; I think you want `MMM` rather than `LLL` (although the docs aren't clear on what `L` means); but that's case-sensitive so you'd still need `Apr` rather than `APR`. Still working on how to make it case-insensitive...

Comment: What does it mean "without any success"? Do you have any error?

Comment: You could create a more permissive DateTimeFormatter class instead of relying on the defaults. For instance: DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .parseLenient()
                .appendPattern("dd-LLL-yyyy hh:mm:ss a")
                .toFormatter()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTimeFormatter month pattern letter "L" fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518954/datetimeformatter-month-pattern-letter-l-fails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MMM` in English will be ***Apr***

`LLL` in English will be ***4***

Please run this snippet - it will explain you a lot:

```
    asList("MMM", "LLL").forEach(ptrn
            -> System.out.println(ptrn + ": " + ofPattern(ptrn, Locale.ENGLISH).format(Month.APRIL))
    );
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
    String textM = "28-Apr-2015 01:25:00 PM";
    DateTimeFormatter formatterM = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(textM, formatterM));

    String textL = "28-4-2015 01:25:00 PM";
    DateTimeFormatter formatterL = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-LLL-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(textL, formatterL));
```

If you need to use ***APR*** then you need to build your own `DateTimeFormatter` using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and set `parseCaseInsensitive` option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of your time pattern issue. you need make sure your time format could matching with the pattern.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

[image]