# How to parse "December 15, 2009" into a Date using Java8 Date API?

Tags: java-8, java-time

Following code does not work:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("L dd, yyyy", Locale.US).parse("December 15, 2009");
```

as it throws

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'December 15, 2009' could not be parsed at index 0
```

How to make it work? Is it even possible using provided `Locale`?? (without using additional Map that maps `String` to month number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `MMMM` instead of `L`:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US).parse("December 15, 2009")
```

I find the javadoc there a little bit confusing. I also marked this one as duplicate to [DateTimeFormatter month pattern letter "L" fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518954/datetimeformatter-month-pattern-letter-l-fails) as it deals mostly with the same issue.

Comment: Strange that it fails, since according to `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` sources, both `M` and `L` denote the same `ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR`.