# Java 8 Date time formatter misbehaving

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time, datetime-parsing

I have the following piece of code that is throwing a `DateTimeParseException`:

```
String dateString = "Jul 20 09:32:46"
DateTimeFormatter formatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("L d HH:mm:ss");
return ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), you will observe that `Jul` is the example for character `L`.

However, the exception message is:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Jul' could not be parsed at index 0

What am I missing?

Comment: the formatter is supposed to put it in that format, not to be able to read that format.

Comment: @Stultuske why does `DateTimeFormatter` has a `parse(CharSequence text)` method then?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer might be wrong about it.

Comment: @user1676688 this might explain a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518954/datetimeformatter-month-pattern-letter-l-fails

Comment: Next to the above comments, without the year supplied, how should the date be determined? Can't guess the year.

Comment: I have this input coming from log of an application. Is it even possible to parse it I wonder?

Comment: Locale problem? “Jul” is not the same in all languages. I recommend you always specify locale with your formatter. Even if you end up going for `Locale.getDefault()`. It will still tell the reader (and yourself) that you have made a conscious choice.

Comment: You can find some references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518954/datetimeformatter-month-pattern-letter-l-fails)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have some issues here:

1. To correctly parse 'Jul' you have to use `MMM` instead of `L` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30519469/7694740) explains why).
2. Your date string doesn't have a year. You can't create a ZonedDateTime without the year.
3. If is a *Zoned* date time, it has to include the time zone information too, which is not in your date string. You can use a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) if you don't want to work with time zones.

Here are some alternatives:

***With timezone:***

```
String dateString = "Jul 20 2018 09:32:46+0000";
DateTimeFormatter formatter= DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd y H:mm:ssZ");
return ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
```

***Without timezone:***

```
String dateString = "Jul 20 2018 09:32:46";
DateTimeFormatter formatter= DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd y H:mm:ss");
return LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
```

Comment: Nitpick: Actually that is an offset-from-UTC rather than a time zone. A zone is a history of changes in offset used by the people of a particular region.

Answer (score 2):

[The answer by Juan Carlos Mendoza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48404165/5772882) is correct. I will give my suggestions as a supplement: either improve your string to include year and time zone, or build a formatter that can parse your current string without them.

**Improving your string**

```
    String dateString = "Jul 20 2018 09:32:46 America/Argentina/La_Rioja";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("LLL d uuuu HH:mm:ss VV", Locale.ROOT);
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter));
```

This prints

```
2018-07-20T09:32:46-03:00[America/Argentina/La_Rioja]
```

The same formatter will also parse `Jul 20 2018 09:32:46 -08:30` into a `ZonedDateTime` of 2018-07-20T09:32:46-08:30.

First potential issue is the locale. If “Jul” is in English, give an English-speaking locale, or parsing will likely fail on computers with a language where the month of July is called something else. I recommend you always specify locale with your formatter. Even if you end up going for `Locale.getDefault()`. It will still tell the reader (and yourself) that you have made a conscious choice.

Next [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) says that both `M` and `L` can give month as number/text and gives examples 7; 07; Jul; July; J. So this line is clearly relevant: “**Number/Text:** If the count of pattern letters is 3 or greater, use the Text rules above. Otherwise use the Number rules above.” Since “Jul” is text, you need 3 pattern letters or greater. “Less than 4 pattern letters will use the short form.” “Jul” is short, so we need exactly three letters.

The code above works with Java 9.0.4 no matter if I use `MMM` or `LLL` in the format pattern string. In jdk1.8.0_131 it works with `MMM` but funnily fails with `LLL`, this may be a bug (tested on a Mac). See Juan Carlos Mendoza’s for a treatment of the intended difference between `M` and `L`.

**Build a formatter that works**

```
    String dateString = "Jul 20 09:32:46";
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Argentina/La_Rioja");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("LLL d HH:mm:ss")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, Year.now(zone).getValue())
            .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT)
            .withZone(zone);
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter));
```

This will parse the string from your question into `2018-07-20T09:32:46-03:00[America/Argentina/La_Rioja]`. Please substitute your desired default time zone if it didn’t happen to coincide with the one I picked at random. Also substitute your desired year if you don’t want the current year.

Again my Java 8 requires `MMM` rather than `LLL`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @JuanCarlosMendoza. See my edit, please.