# DateTimeFormatter throwing exception "could not be parsed at index 0"

Tags: java, android, java-time

I keep on getting an error from running this code.

java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Jan 03, 2020' could not be parsed at index 0

```
final String myFormat = "LLL dd, yyyy"; //sets format in which to show date (same as how its saved in database) ex. Jan 29, 2020
final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(myFormat);

String startingBiWeeklyCheck = sharedPreferences.getString("biweekly start", "Jan 03, 2020");
            LocalDate startingDate = LocalDate.parse(startingBiWeeklyCheck, dateFormatter);
```

Ive played around with the format but I'm not seeing why the pattern "LLL dd, yyyy" doesn't parse Jan 03, 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `MMM` instead of `LLL` for month parsing.

**Updated:**

I was wrong about my answer above. It's the half of answer.

The deal is `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(myFormat)` uses default `Locale`.
For non-US locales, it doesn't work.
So you need to specify the locale according to your pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(myFormat).withLocale(Locale.US)
```

Comment: changing the format to "MMM dd, yyyy" is throwing the same exception.

Comment: Check your `startingBiWeeklyCheck` variable output. It should always return a string with the same pattern as you specified in `myFormat`

Comment: By the way, what's your locale? Try also set `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(myFormat).withLocale(Locale.US)`

Comment: @Ole V.V. It's actually interesting because take look the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)
`M/L     month-of-year               number/text       7; 07; Jul; July; J`. So the L represents number and M represents text value. On my `AdoptOpenJDK 1.8.0_262-b10` it's vise versa!

Comment: Here is my output https://pastebin.com/MnrFwJrb

Comment: I've just mentioned that's the question marked as duplicated and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518954/datetimeformatter-month-pattern-letter-l-fails has an explanation about this behavior.

Comment: I admit that the documentation that you quote is easy to misunderstand. `MM` and `LL` are both month number. `MMM` and `LLL` are both month abbreviations, only in a few languages they are different forms. The documentation also says: “**Number/Text:** If the count of pattern letters is 3 or greater, use the Text rules above. Otherwise use the Number rules above.”